# Home button starts game from beginning?

Tags: android, onresume, onpause, android-homebutton

I'm playing my game. While playing, I press the home button on my Android phone. Then I press the game Icon on my Android screen, and the game starts from beginning. I know there is OnApplicationPause. But what should I add there? How can I continue my game from the position where I left the game?

Comment: There is a TON of information on this and it really depends on how you code your game as to how you retain state through pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really depends on your situation but basically save your gameState in onPause and load it in onResume
Please read: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html